# Getting the real keyCode in keydown event

Tags: jquery, keydown, keycode

Suppose I am listening for the keydown event on an input field:

```
$input.on('keydown', function(e) {

});
```

I actually want to listen for the number keys in combination with the shift key. So basically I want to determine if the user pressed a number in combination with the shift key.

For the number block this works as expected:

```
if(e.shiftKey && e.which >= 98 && e.which < 106) {
    var number = e.which - 98;
}
```

I would expect the "normal" number keys to return the keyCodes 48 - 57. But, at least in Safari 7.1, pressing shift + 2 returns the keyCode 222 (quotes) and shift + 7 returns 191 (slash).

My question: Why this inconsistent behavior? How can I get the actual keyCode (meaning 49 for shift+2 for example)?

Comment: mapping would be sufficient for this I guess.